# Vertical accordion table not workwing with a responsive web design layout

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

Hey so I have an issue with a vertical accordion FAQ table and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help.  I would like for this to work in a responsive design I am using.  When on the iPad or an iPhone, the right side of the accordion does not show and does not allow you to scroll to the right essentially making it completion unusable on the smaller devices such as phones.  Any ideas??

Here is the code:

```css
.accordion {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #542437;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 877px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.accordion ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.accordion li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.accordion [type=radio],
.accordion [type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background: #652c8f;
  border: 1px solid #542437;
  color: #d2ae52;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.accordion ul li label:hover,
.accordion [type=radio]:checked ~ label,
.accordion [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
  background: #652c8f;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.accordion .content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  /* Make the border match the background so it fades in nicely */
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.accordion p {
  color: #652c8f;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.accordion h3 {
  color: #652c8f;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
/* Vertical */

.vertical ul li {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
}
.vertical ul li label {
  padding: 10px;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label,
.vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.vertical ul li label:hover {
  border: 1px solid #542437;
  /* We don't want the border to disappear on hover */
}
.vertical ul li .content {
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 0;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content,
.vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #542437;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion vertical">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-accordion" />
      <label for="checkbox-1" align="center">THE KING CHANEL WAY</label>
      <div class="content">
        <br />
        <p>King Chanel for Hair is pleased to say that we are supplying you with authentic unprocessed Virgin Temple Indian Hair that is donated from the heads of Indian women on an annual basis as a part of their spiritual journey. Once the hair has been
          properly sorted and sterilized it is sold directly to you! Our hair is guaranteed to last 2+ years with proper care and maintenance. It is well known that in the Indian culture they use natural products on their hair, opposed to harsh chemicals,
          resulting in their hair to be very thick, healthy and strong with an amazing texture! Upon receiving your Virgin Indian Temple Hair you should try your best to continue to use natural products to maintain your tresses. Below we will be providing
          some suggestions that should aid in keeping your extensions in tip top shape for many years to come!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-accordion" />
      <label for="checkbox-2" align="center">VIRGIN INDIAN HAIR DONT'S:</label>
      <div class="content">
        <br />
        <p>♛ Do NOT use products that contain alcohol! If it is an absolute must, use the product sparingly.</p>
        <p>♛ Do NOT sew through the wefts.</p>
        <p>♛ Do NOT forget to use a HEAT PROTECTANT when straightening your virgin hair.</p>
        <p>♛ Do NOT load up your Indian hair with styling products, that is not necessary with pure virgin hair, the less product the more beautiful it will look :).</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox-accordion" />
      <label for="checkbox-3" align="center">VIRGIN INDIAN HAIR DO'S:</label>
      <div class="content">
        <br />
        <p>♛ DO be sure to keep hair clean by using a gentle sulfate free shampoo at least once per month (or prior to straightening).</p>
        <p>♛ DO co-wash at least once per week.</p>
        <p>♛ DO detangle hair prior to washing with a wide tooth comb, combing from tip to root.</p>
        <p>♛ DO LIGHTLY oil your Indian hair to help maintain its health (we suggest using pure virgin coconut oil).</p>
        <p>♛ DO braid down or tie up your hair (pineapple) with a silk/satin scarf at night (although not necessary, this will allow you to have wake up and go hair!).</p>
        <p>♛ DO SUBMIT your hair photos to us to share on our social media sites!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the list elements which are not needed and I have stripped the CSS a little to make the example smaller.

- Change your width to a `max-width` and allow the container to expand / contract
- Change the height to `max-height: 0` with a transition to `max-height: 500px`. This will allow for the height to match the content and eliminates the need for scrollbars. It can be improved a little by tweaking the selected max height separately for each content div.
- Use the `+` selector instead of `~` to only select the immediate div / label. Now on click only the selected label will get a color change.

### Working Example

**Note:** In this example I have removed the prefixes for `transition`. Reconsider the need for prefixed transition as [the unprefixed property is heavily supported (including IE10+)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). If you do use the prefix, then place the unprefixed property underneath for modern browsers.

```css
.accordion {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #542437;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 877px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.accordion [type=radio],
.accordion [type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #652c8f;
  border: 1px solid #542437;
  color: #d2ae52;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .5s;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.accordion label:hover,
.accordion [type=radio]:checked + label,
.accordion [type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #652c8f;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.accordion .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1.2s;
  max-height: 0;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked + label + .content,
.vertical [type=checkbox]:checked + label + .content {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion vertical">

  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-accordion" />
  <label for="checkbox-1" align="center">THE KING CHANEL WAY</label>

  <div class="content">

    <p>King Chanel for Hair is pleased to say that we are supplying you with authentic unprocessed Virgin Temple Indian Hair that is donated from the heads of Indian women on an annual basis as a part of their spiritual journey. Once the hair has been properly
      sorted and sterilized it is sold directly to you! Our hair is guaranteed to last 2+ years with proper care and maintenance. It is well known that in the Indian culture they use natural products on their hair, opposed to harsh chemicals, resulting
      in their hair to be very thick, healthy and strong with an amazing texture! Upon receiving your Virgin Indian Temple Hair you should try your best to continue to use natural products to maintain your tresses. Below we will be providing some suggestions
      that should aid in keeping your extensions in tip top shape for many years to come!</p>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-accordion" />
  <label for="checkbox-2" align="center">VIRGIN INDIAN HAIR DONT'S:</label>
  <div class="content">

    <p>♛ Do NOT use products that contain alcohol! If it is an absolute must, use the product sparingly.</p>
    <p>♛ Do NOT sew through the wefts.</p>
    <p>♛ Do NOT forget to use a HEAT PROTECTANT when straightening your virgin hair.</p>
    <p>♛ Do NOT load up your Indian hair with styling products, that is not necessary with pure virgin hair, the less product the more beautiful it will look :).</p>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox-accordion" />
  <label for="checkbox-3" align="center">VIRGIN INDIAN HAIR DO'S:</label>
  <div class="content">

    <p>♛ DO be sure to keep hair clean by using a gentle sulfate free shampoo at least once per month (or prior to straightening).</p>
    <p>♛ DO co-wash at least once per week.</p>
    <p>♛ DO detangle hair prior to washing with a wide tooth comb, combing from tip to root.</p>
    <p>♛ DO LIGHTLY oil your Indian hair to help maintain its health (we suggest using pure virgin coconut oil).</p>
    <p>♛ DO braid down or tie up your hair (pineapple) with a silk/satin scarf at night (although not necessary, this will allow you to have wake up and go hair!).</p>
    <p>♛ DO SUBMIT your hair photos to us to share on our social media sites!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```